# Опрос Com-порта в Linux C++

Tags: c++, linux, rs232

Есть задача опроса Сом-порта не реже чем раз в 20-30мс на древнем Linux(2.4.32).Реализовано через таймер Linux(setitimer(ITIMER_REAL)).
Заметил,что  при отрисовке графики (Qt 3.3) по результатам приема, интервалы таймера не выдерживаются и соответственно прием сбоит- происходит пропуск байт. Как можно решить  эту проблему? Есть возможность настроить программный высокоточный таймер?
P.S. Или как правильно организовать прием, если нельзя -)

Сам код:
// инициализация портов

```
bool TCom::OpenPort(speed_t speed, int num)
{
    switch(num)
    {
    case RD:
        strcpy(port,"/dev/ttyS0");
        break;
    case WR:
        strcpy(port,"/dev/ttyS2");
        break;
    }

    Id = open(port,O_RDWR|O_NOCTTY);
    if(Id == -1)
    {
    char* msg = strerror(errno);
    printf("%s\n",msg);
    TCom::flag = num;
    return false;
    }
    
    tcgetattr(Id,&options);
        
    options.c_iflag=0;
           
    options.c_cc[VTIME] = 20; 
    options.c_cc[VMIN] = 32;                    
    
    options.c_cflag &= ~PARENB;
    options.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;
    options.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE;
    options.c_cflag |=CS8;
    options.c_lflag =0;    
    options.c_oflag &= ~OPOST;
        
    cfsetispeed(&options,speed);
    cfsetospeed(&options,speed);        
    
    tcsetattr(Id,TCSANOW,&options);
        
    tcflush(Id,TCIOFLUSH);
    return true;
}
```

// приемник

```
int TCom::TrySelect()
{
  fd_set set;  
  timeval tv;
  tv.tv_sec =0;
  tv.tv_usec=35000;
  FD_ZERO(&set);
  FD_SET(Id,&set);
  select(Id+1,&set,NULL,NULL,NULL/*&tv*/);
  if(FD_ISSET(Id,&set))
  {
     //ReadPort(MassIn,32); 
      return 1;
  }
  
  return 0;
}
```

//создание потока

```
int InitThread()
{
 pthread_attr_t attr;
 struct sched_param sched;
       
    if(pthread_attr_init(&attr)) {printf("Error init attrs\n");return -1;}
    
    if(pthread_attr_setschedpolicy(&attr,SCHED_FIFO)) printf("Error schedpolicy!\n");
    if(int Result = pthread_create(&tid,&attr,&GetCommState,NULL))
       printf("Error,Can't create thread:[%s]\n ",strerror(Result));
   else
       printf("Thread created successfully!\n");
}
```

//Вопрос, нужно ли писать в порт2 (/dev/ttyS1) в отдельном потоке, не потоке чтения?

Comment: Обычно это делается через poll() или select()

Comment: Опрос реализован через ioctl(fd, FIONREAD, &bytes) +  read()

Comment: Ну вот вместо того, чтобы опрос крутить в цикле, сядьте ниткой в select()